# What does and in python stands for

Tags: python

I try some samples in python console. And was confused for the following:

```
>>> (1 and None)
>>> (1 and None) == None
True
>>> (1 or None) == None
False
>>> (1 and 2) == 2
True
>>> (2 and 1) == 2
False
>>> (2 and 1) == 1
True
```

I was confused for what is the why (1 and None) does not return any thing is line 1? It should be None? And why (2 and 1) equals to 1 but not 2. Sorry for new with Python.

Comment: Try `print(1 and None)`. Shell doesn't print `None` unless explicitly told to print.

Comment: For why `None` is not displayed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639342/none-is-not-displayed-as-i-expected-in-python-interactive-mode

Comment: See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing (4.1 and 4.2)

Comment: @JRodDynamite It prints None! But why 1 and 2 will print 2, I think is should be 1 & 2 which return 0....

Comment: `1 and 2` is not the same as `1 & 2`.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/4014959) help?

Comment: I believe this is the answer You are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18195382/6411000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, 
empty string, dict, tuple, list are False.
The others are True

`(1 and None)` is same as `if 1 is False return 1 else None`
that is why (1 and None) return None

same reason == > (2 and 1) return 1 so, it's not 2.

My English isn't good, you can find more information from below links

1. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing
2. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations